# Spring & AngularJS : Undefined status for PUT method

Tags: angularjs, ajax, spring

i am returning a string on updation of a record and want to show the same string on UI(updated successfully)

Here is my code :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/update")
    public @ResponseBody String update(@RequestParam("id") int id, @RequestParam("name") String name) {
        employeeService.update(id, name);
        return "updated successfully";
```

front end code :

```
$scope.update = function(Employee) {
                    $http({
                        method : 'PUT',
                        url : '/Employee/update',
                        params : {
                            id : Employee.id,
                            name : Employee.name
                        }
                    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.updatedText = data;
                        $scope.updatedFlag = true;
                    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log("data.token " + data.token);
                    });
                };
```

Here are two interesting screen shots

[image]

> here status is undefined

again

[image]

> here status is 200

please let me know what is the reason behind that and yes i can see that there is a change in the hibernate table

Please help

Comment: I must admit, this issue is very tricky. Maybe https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http can help you out.

Comment: uhm  `.error()` and  `.success()` were deprecated. also they work with one parameter that's  `response` as an example an they throw you an object with the response of the server. also i think you should work with promises to receive better your data.

Answer (score 0):

Well i'll leave you an example how i handle calls to the `API` with `$http` and promises `$q`

i use it inside a service, that can be injected on my controllers.

```
this.update = function (Employee) {
    var datosRecu = null;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var token = $cookies.getObject('token');
    $http({
        url: '/Employee/update',
        method: 'PUT',
        params: {
            id: Employee.id,
            name: Employee.name
        },
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        datosRecu = response;
        deferred.resolve(datosRecu);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        datosRecu = response;
        deferred.resolve(datosRecu);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

now when i inject it on my controller i can read the promise `deferred.promise` with all the data of response.

i hope it help you.